# Multiple Services with Google App Engine Flexible Environments

Tags: google-app-engine

With normal app engine, you can define Services (previously called modules) by creating versions of app.yaml.  It seems with Flexible Environments you can't do that anymore, that it in fact crashes when using the old module: name syntax and throws errors with the term service: name.

Any ideas how to run multiple types of processes with Flexible Environment in the same project?

Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

I'm using this app.yaml and it's working fine for me:

```
runtime: custom
env: flex

service: hello-world
```

Answer (score 0):

The [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml) about currently seems to be wrong. Try using `module:` instead of `service:` in your `app.yaml` file just like the Standard Environment. It works for me.

Comment: This is wrong. They precisely say Note: Services were previously called "modules.". I'm using service: in my app.yaml and it's working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use multiple **app.yaml** files. and then deploy them separately
`gcloud app deploy` -> deploys my API
`gcloud app deploy queue-worker.yaml` -> deploys another service i have.

if you want them to share the same code, but have different entrypoints, or different docker environments. 
Then you could build a separate docker image and push it to GCR and then specify it when you deploy

heres an example:
`gcloud app deploy queue-processor-app.yaml --image-url eu.gcr.io/my-proj/queue-processor`

see my answer here for slightly more detail:
[Multiple services with different dockerfiles on GAE Flexible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49388615/multiple-services-with-different-dockerfiles-on-gae-flexible/58119935#58119935)